# Is it possible to read a report in a netsuite restlet script?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

We are using suitscript 2.0. We would like to read a custom report from netsuite periodically and persist the data into a third party system. It seems that neither the search module nor the record module can load/read reports data. Is it possible to get the report data programatically or not?

Comment: Hello, were you able to find a way to programmatically extract the report data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NetSuite reports are not scriptable.  Your only option is to re-create the report as a saved search which can be read via SuiteScript.